# Why am I getting undefined instead of null?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, null

I wrote a function that returns a day of the week given a number (1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday etc) and I was supposed to create a caveat where if the number was less than 1 or greater than 7, the function should return null. Why is it instead returning undefined for 0 and 8?

```js
daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

function returnDay(day) {
  day = daysOfWeek[day - 1];
  if (day > 7 || day < 1) {
    return null
  } else {
    return day
  }
}

console.log(returnDay(8))
console.log(returnDay(0))
```

Comment: Maybe the item of `daysOfWeek` at index `day - 1` is undefined? May you share an example where you call the function, along with an example of `daysOfWeek`?

Comment: Please add `daysOfWeek` to the question.

Comment: `day = daysOfWeek[day-1];` You're overwriting `day`, so it's no longer going to be a number after this point. So the check on the line after this isn't going to work as you expect it to.

Comment: You are re-assigning to `day` before checking whether the input is valid.

Comment: note the very first thing you do in your function, *before* your if

Comment: Test the parameter _before_ attempting to access the array — `function returnDay(day) { return (day < 1 || day > 7) ? null : daysOfWeek[day - 1]; }`

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting your argument, which is considered bad practice.

When you access `daysOfWeek[0 -1]` => `daysOfWeek[-1]` => `undefined`, you then evaluate is `undefined < 1` which is `falsy`. So you enter the else, which returns `day` => `undefined`

The below code works

```
daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

function returnDay(day) {
  if (day <= 7 && day >= 1) {
    return daysOfWeek[day - 1]
  }
  return null
}

console.log(returnDay(8))
console.log(returnDay(0))
```

Or, even more dense

```
daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

function returnDay = d => daysOfWeek[d - 1] || null

console.log(returnDay(8))
console.log(returnDay(0))
```

Comment: The same issue here. What if `daysOfWeek` size change for some reason? You'll have to adjust two things in your code, not one. And yes, another good point was just given in the answer the OP gave.

Comment: Another note, when you have multiple variables that represent the a similar concept, it helps it distinguish them in the variable name. In this case 'dayIndex' and 'dayTitle` would work well, it helps avoid the headache you are having here

Comment: @raina77ow I do not expect the days of the week to change anytime soon. However in principle you are correct, and it would be better to reference the daysOfWeek.length.

For that matter, this works but it's less obvious why it works for a beginner. 

`day => daysOfWeek[day-1] || null`

Comment: It works, because it tries to fetch a title for given day - and gives a default value if fetch failed. That's as straightforward as it can be. Checking against range is error-prone by definition; one example was just given in the OP's post.

Comment: We're splitting hairs at this point, but I do not think short-circuit evaluations is the best way to teach a new developer. Maybe you think it is, that's fine.

Comment: You miss the main point here: when checking, don't check twice. In the best case, you'll end up doing things just for the sake of doing them. In the worst, the code might end up in the middle of nowhere when 1st check passes yet 2nd fails. And yes, in this example it doesn't matter; the problem is, someone will look at that code and take it as is for a _dynamic_ enum, still thinking checking the boundary range explicitly is fine. Then, one day, a quite different someone will casually drop an element from that enum, raising a bug that'll be really hard to spot.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two range checks in your code right now, and that's the biggest issue.

Here's the first check:

```
day = daysOfWeek[day - 1];
```

... which ends with `undefined` unless `day` has valid value (so that there's an element in `daysOfWeek` that corresponds to that value).

And here's the second check:

```
if (day > 7 || day < 1) { ... }
```

... which ends up doing wrong things because `day` variable gets a different value in that line of the first check. You can fix this, of course, by introducing another name...

```
const dayTitle = daysOfWeek[day - 1];
if (day > 7 || day < 1) { ... }
```

... but that means you're still checking the same condition **twice**. And it's never a good idea to repeat yourself.

So here's how it can be done:

```
function returnDay(day) {
  return daysOfWeek[day - 1] || null;
}
```

... yep, that simple: the boundary range check now is done by JS, not you and your code. In other words, if `day` value cannot be used as a proper index for that `dayOfWeek` array, you'll just get `undefined` (which will be coalesced by `|| null` to, well, `null`).

And yes, having `null` as kind of default value in this case seems weird to me.

Answer (score -1):

So I changed the arguement so that day is no longer being overwritten and it looks like this:

```
function returnDay(n){
    day = daysOfWeek[n-1];
    if (n  > 7 || n  < 1){
        return null
    } else {
        return day
    }
}
console.log(returnDay(8))
console.log(returnDay(0))
```

I now successfully get null for returnDay(0) and returnDay(8)

Comment: Indexes in JS start with 0, not 1; there's no element for `day[7]`. But that's actually another good point why checking range explicitly is bad.

Comment: Both of the other answers are better because they explain what's going on and why it should be changed. - Remember, SO isn't here _just to help you_, but to also help others with similar issues.